# Amazon EC2: Is it ok to delete snapshot while it's being copied

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, snapshot

We have a process of creating snapshot and copying them to other region. Previously I thought that only after copying progress completed I can delete the original one, but just find out that even if I delete the source snapshot right after triggering copying it to other region, the copying progress still works and reaches to 100% and target snapshot becomes available.

So, is it safe to do that, if yes it would be convenient as we don't need to run & check periodically for copying progress before deleting original snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

It is risky to do that. If the copying fails the snapshot will be lost.

If you delete the snapshot the file is likely not deleted right away because the copy process holds file lock on the snapshot. If that copy process fails for whatever reason the data is lost.